# Apache mod_rewrite to change file extension

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to change all requests to a file with the extension .user.js to be made to a .php.
I have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([^/]*)\.user\.js$ $1.php [R,NC]

</ifModule>
```

That unfortunately does not work.
I know mod_rewrite is loaded because, if I do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([^/]*)\.user\.js$ $1.php [R,NC]
s
</ifModule>
```

It returns a status code of 500. So I believe my problem is in the regex.
Example of what I want:

```
GET /foo/bar/preetyuserscript.user.js
```

becomes

```
GET /foo/bar/preetyuserscript.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.user\.js$ $1.php
```

If it doesn't and you continue to see 500 errors have a look in the error log. Always the first place to check out.

Comment: It works, thx. I even changed it to this to speed up the process:^(.*)\.user\.js$ $1.php I had already tried one almost like this but without the '\'. Probably it was browser cache fault. I only mentioned the error 500 was so that I could proove that mod_rewrite is available

Answer (score 1):

Correct RewriteRule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.user\.js$ /$1.php [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: does not work. That rewrite sends the request to the root of the server. I don't want that.

Comment: Are you sure, in my testing this URI `/foo/bar/preetyuserscript.user.js` is becoming `/foo/bar/preetyuserscript.php`. Do you have some other rules in your .htaccess file? Can you also paste access.log snippets as well.